# What is going wrong with my switch function?

Tags: c, switch-statement, argv

What is going wrong with my switch function?
it looks like this

```
void ss(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int side_length = 200;
  double red = 0.0;
  double green = 0.0;
  double blue = 0.0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= argc; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    if (*argv[i] == '-'){
      switch (*++argv[i]) {
        case 'r':
          red = sin(0.2*atof(argv[i++]));
          printf("argv: %f\n", sin(0.2*atof(argv[i++])));
          printf("red: %f\n", red);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm planning to add more switch cases later, but right now I'm focusing on red so I can just replicate it. It seems like the problem is in that it just doesn't store the value I want it to in red, it returns the value in the other printf statement just fine.

edit: I have since used both for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) and for (int i = 1; argv[i] != '\0'; i++) and neither have worked. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Seems like you have way too many pre-increment and post-increment operators.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you elaborate? Sorry, I'm new to C.

Comment: Your code has several problems. On is, that your for loop run to far ... ` for (int i = 1; i <= argc; i++)` should be ` for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)`.

Comment: Try printing out the command line arguments with code like this `for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){printf("(%s)\n",argv[i]); for(int j=0;argv[i][j]!='\0';j++){printf("'%c' ",argv[i][j]);}putchar('\n');}`  Then see if you can use something similar to accomplish your task.

Comment: @user3386109 that code looks pretty similar to the one I had, just with an additional printing function, although printing the chars isn't really what I'm trying to accomplish. That was just testing to make sure what I was doing worked. The value still isn't stored to "red", with this code.

Comment: Isn't 'char * argv[] specifying an array is a pointer to a parameter of type char?  Is this intended?  Could you use simply char[] instead, and pass in the name of the array as a pointer to its first position?  Maybe a type issue is preventing the if statement from executing.  What output are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do too much at once with the increment operator.  As a result, you get confused as to what the code is doing.  Specifically, you increment `i` twice inside of the loop when calculating the sine.

Break out the extra increment only when it's needed:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    if (argv[i][0] == '-'){     // check the first char of the current arg
      switch (argv[i][1]) {     // check the second char of the current arg
        case 'r':
          red = sin(0.2*atof(argv[i+1]));   // grab the value from the next arg
          printf("argv: %f\n", sin(0.2*atof(argv[i+1])));   // grab the next arg again
          printf("red: %f\n", red);
          i++;                  // do an extra increment at the end since we processed 2 args
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the too many `i++` operations, your program invokes *undefined behavior*, since you access the `argv` array out of bounds.

After that, you cannot say anything about the program's behavior. It is even allowed to delete all your files.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I have since updated the for loop to be `for(i=1;i<argc;i++)`, but it still won't update red. Is there some other problem that it's running into or is the original problem not solved yet?